# Multiple relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables:

- candidates [id, family_name, etc]
- consultants [id, family_name, etc]
- meetings [id, consultant_id, etc]
- candidate_meeting [id, candidate_id, meeting_id]

A meeting has only one consultant, a meeting has several candidates.
I would like to find all the candidates of a consultant.

Unfortunately I can't do it, either through "Has Many Through" relationship or polymorphic relationships.

Could you tell me if the database schema's suitable for eloquent use or should I modify the schema?

Thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for a direct relationship.

I've created a package for cases like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```php
class Consultant extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function candidates()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Candidate::class, [Meeting::class, 'candidate_meeting']);
    }
}

Consultant::find($id)->candidates;
```